# how to define the microservice self registry address to consul in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, consul

I want to registry my java spring boot microservice into consul in kubernetes cluster, first step I add the consul dependencies using gradle:

```
implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery"
```

now I define the consul config like this in `application.properties`:

```
# registry center
spring.cloud.consul.host=consul-1630121482-headless.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local
spring.cloud.consule.port=8500
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-interval=15s
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.instance-id= ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
```

but the consul shows error like this:

```
Get "http://dolphin-post-service-78f88c8c54-nrfbz:11014/actuator/health": dial tcp: lookup dolphin-post-service-78f88c8c54-nrfbz on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

the consul access my service by pod name, so how to make the consul access the right url? I think the url should look like:

```
dolphin-post-service-78f88c8c54-nrfbz.dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local
```

so what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this config to `applicaton.properties` use ip address:

```
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.prefer-ip-address= true
```